# Pandas Dataframe : How to flatten nested dictionaries inside a list into new rows

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to flatten API response.
This is the response

```
data = [{
            "id": 1,
            "status": "Public",
            "Options": [
                  {
                        "id": 8,
                        "pId": 9
                  },
                  {
                      "id": 10,
                        "pId": 11
                  }
               ]
},      
        {
            "id": 2,
            "status": "Public",
            "Options": [
                  {
                        "id": 12,
                        "pId": 13
                  },
                  {
                      "id": 14,
                        "pId": 15
                  }
               ]
}

]
```

I am trying to do this(applying ast literal eval, df.pop and json normalize).
And then i am concatinating the results

```
def pop(child_df, column_value):

    child_df = child_df.dropna(subset=[column_value])
    if isinstance(child_df[column_value][0], str):
        print("yes")
        child_df[column_value] = child_df[column_value].apply(ast.literal_eval)
    normalized_json = [json_normalize(x) for x in child_df.pop(column_value)]
    expanded_child_df = child_df.join(pd.concat(normalized_json, ignore_index=True, sort=False).add_prefix(column_value + '_'))
    expanded_child_df.columns = [str(col).replace('\r','') for col in expanded_child_df.columns]
    expanded_child_df.columns = map(str.lower, expanded_child_df.columns)

    return expanded_child_df

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

df2 = pop(df,'Options')
```

This is the output i am getting

```
   id  status  options_id  options_pid
0   1  Public           8            9
1   2  Public          10           11
```

But the code is skipping some values inside the `Options` list.
This is the expected output

```
   id  status  options_id  options_pid
0   1  Public           8            9
1   1  Public           10           11
2   2  Public          12           13
3   2  Public          14           15
```

What am i missing here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path="Options", meta=['id','status'], record_prefix='options.')
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use:

```
df=pd.json_normalize(data).explode('Options')
df=df.join(df['Options'].apply(pd.Series).add_prefix('options_')).drop(['Options'],axis=1).drop_duplicates()
print(df)
'''
   id  status  optionsid  optionspId
0   1  Public          8           9
0   1  Public         10          11
1   2  Public         12          13
1   2  Public         14          15
'''
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
df = pd.json_normalize(data).explode('Options')
tmp= df['Options'].apply(pd.Series)
df = pd.concat([df[['id', 'status']], tmp], axis=1)
print(df)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?